# Dataclasses: Matching Generic TypeVar names to attributes in the origin class

Tags: python, generics, annotations, type-hinting, python-typing

Say I have a Generic dataclass like the following:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import TypeVar, Generic

T = TypeVar('T')
U = TypeVar('U')


@dataclass
class Class(Generic[T, U]):
    foo: U
    bar: T


IntStrClass = Class[int, str]
```

When we read the code you can see that for `IntStrClass`:

- the `T` lines up with `int`, which makes the type of `bar` an `int`.
- the `U` lines up with `str`, which makes the type of `foo` a `str`.

**But how can I figure this out progamatically?**

I've been playing around with the `typing` module, but can't see from the outputs how I would match them up. What I have is:

```
from typing import get_type_hints, get_origin, get_args

print("Class field types:", get_type_hints(get_origin(IntStrClass)))
print("Class generic args:", get_args(IntStrClass))
```

```
Class field types: {'foo': ~U, 'bar': ~T}
Class generic args: (<class 'int'>, <class 'str'>)
```

What I'm missing here is from the definition of `Class`, to determine that `T -> int` and `U -> str`. If I had this information, then I could infer the proper types of `foo` and `bar`.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this?

[Has been significantly edited following a conversation in the comments.]

```
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import TypeVar, Generic, get_type_hints, get_args, get_origin

T = TypeVar('T')
U = TypeVar('U')


@dataclass
class Class(Generic[T, U]):
    foo: U
    spam: str
    bar: T
    baz: int


IntStrClass = Class[int, str]

def get_annotations(generic_subclass):
    generic_origin = get_origin(generic_subclass)
    annotations_map = get_type_hints(generic_origin)
    generic_args = get_args(generic_subclass)

    try:
        generic_params = generic_origin.__parameters__
    except AttributeError as err:
        raise AttributeError(
            f"{origin} has no attribute '__parameters__'. "
            "The likely cause of this is that the typing module's "
            "API for the Generic class has changed "
            "since this function was written."
            ) from err

    type_var_map = dict(zip(generic_params, generic_args))
    
    for field, annotation in annotations_map.items():
        if isinstance(annotation, TypeVar):
            annotations_map[field] = type_var_map[annotation]
            
    return annotations_map

print("Resolved attributes:", get_annotations(IntStrClass))
```

```
Resolved attributes: {'foo': <class 'str'>, 'spam': <class 'str'>, 'bar': <class 'int'>, 'baz': <class 'int'>}
```

Comment: I think you're on the right track, but the type for `foo` should be `str`. I've found the attribute `Class.__parameters__` from grepping the typing module that I think puts me on the right track. That gives back `(~T, ~U)` to line up with `(<class 'int'>, <class 'str'>)` provided from `get_args(IntStrClass)`

Comment: Shoot, I missed that you'd reversed the order of the TypeVars in your class definition. Very sneaky.

Comment: Okay, I posted what I have so far, but it feels super hacky.

Comment: I've just edited my post to give my second take. I don't think there's a way round having to use the `__parameters__` attribute (unless you want to write something parsing Python source code using the `inspect` module and regular expressions, which... yuck). However, I think I'd rather the function raised an explicit exception -- which I could then catch later on -- rather than have it fail silently and return `None`.

Comment: It is definitely frustrating how many functions and attributes in the `typing` module are marked as private, and how many attributes (like `__parameters__`) are undocumented even though they're not officially marked "private". Just have to keep reminding myself how new the `typing` module still is, and the extent to which it's still under active development.

Comment: Giving you the check mark for putting me on the right path. I’m working on making this function for nested generic types now, say `list[list[dict[T, U]]]`. Interesting rabbit hole :)

Answer (score 2):

I think I might have found a solution, but I'm not sure how safe it is. The generic subclass seems to expose a `__parameters__` field which I think I can leverage here:

```
def get_hints(clazz):
    origin = get_origin(clazz)
    hints = get_type_hints(origin)
    clazz_args = get_args(clazz)
    if hasattr(origin, "__parameters__"):
        typevars = origin.__parameters__
        for typevar, resolved_typevar in zip(typevars, clazz_args):
            for attr_name in hints:
                if hints[attr_name] == typevar:
                    hints[attr_name] = resolved_typevar
    return hints
```

Testing this with Alex Waygood's example:

```
T = TypeVar('T')
U = TypeVar('U')


@dataclass
class Class(Generic[T, U]):
    foo: U
    spam: str
    bar: T
    baz: int


IntStrClass = Class[int, str]
print("Resolved attributes:", get_hints(IntStrClass))
```

```
Resolved attributes: {'foo': <class 'str'>, 'spam': <class 'str'>, 'bar': <class 'int'>, 'baz': <class 'int'>}
```

I'm sure there's some corner cases I'm missing.

Comment: Could always post this on CodeReview, given that it's now working code, and see if anybody can think of something more elegant and/or can spot any edge cases you or I have missed